# eclipse and VC++6: NMAKE fatal error U1073

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-c++, visual-c++-6

I keep getting this error when I try to conifg my `Eclipse` to debug my `VC6` program:

```
NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'LN_BASE.CPP'
```

Any advice?

Comment: It usually happens when you have source file 'LN_BASE.cpp' included in your project but in practice such file doesn't really exist so NMake doesn't know how to compile non-existing file ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because nmake cannot find the src file;

i
 move the code file from src dir to project root dir, then the problem solved.